# retrieving data from mysql select statement in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Having trouble with this..I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I simply want the result of a select statement in a java mysql select statement but I keep getting:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@1c190c99
```

Here's my code:

```
PreparedStatement Findstatement;
                Findstatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Code from DataMaster where DataName= (?) ");
                Findstatement.setString(1, Name);  // I have a variable in my file named 'Name' 
                ResultSet CodeAll  = Findstatement.executeQuery();
                System.out.println(CodeAll);
```

I've tried int fundCode = fundCodeAll.getInt(1); at the end of the statement but still no luck.  How do I get the int value of the the result from the select statement?

Comment: Its probably a better idea to use java.sql.ResultSet -- unless the mysql resultset gives you amazing performance improvements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `ResultSet` by `ResultSet#next()` and then get the column values by any of the `ResultSet` getters.

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    int code = resultSet.getInt("Code");
    // ...
}
```

If there are zero or many results, then you can collect them in a `List`.

```
List<Integer> codes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// ...
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    codes.add(resultSet.getInt("Code"));
}
// ...
```

Or if there is zero or one result, then replace `while` by `if`.

```
int code = 0;
// ...
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
if (resultSet.next()) {
    code = resultSet.getInt("Code");
}
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, please pay attention to the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: ohhh I saw that but didn't think I had to do it if there was only one result.  I saw this in examples but it was all for multiple results.  Guess I was being too lazy :-)  Thanks so much BalusC!

Comment: If there's guaranteed to be zero or one result, then you can also replace `while` by `if`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I understood this for multiple results but yes in this example its always going to be one result.  If I have multiple id codes for the same products then this resultset is going to be the least of my problems :-)

Comment: Sounds like your key problem was that you missed that you need to say resultSet.next() to get the next record. If there's only one record, you still need to call next() once to get the first record.

Comment: Yes, the initial cursor position is *before* the row.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the resultset, you should iterate over it:

```
while(CodeAll.next()){

    String value = CodeAll.getString("column name");

    //get all values depending on type, like getString for string, 
    //getDouble for double, etc
}
```

Just get values from result set and do whatever you want from it.