# Mysql query returns single record in servlet. How do I print it?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

The code I've written is

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.sql.Connection; 
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet; 
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement; 
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Search extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection con =null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String veh_no = request.getParameter("vehicle_no");
        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pay_n_park","root","admin");             
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select block_no from vehicle where vehicle_no='"+veh_no+"' and out_time=NULL");
            if(rs != null){
                out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<head>");
                out.println("<title>Search Results</title>");            
                out.println("</head>");
                out.println("<body>");
                out.println("<h1>Search Results :</h1>");
                out.print("<br/> Vehicle No: " + veh_no);
                out.print("<br/> Block No  : " + rs.getString("block_no"));
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>");
            }


        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}// </editor-fold>
```

The result set `rs` has only one record. If I do `rs.next()`, it comes out of `if`, I don't want that.
What should I do to print this record, it is coming out of the `if` in both the cases.

Comment: Got the error it was returning empty set. The query should be > rs = stmt.executeQuery("select block_no from vehicle where vehicle_no='"+veh_no+"' and out_time is NULL"); Just replaced '=' with 'is' .

Answer (score 0):

The returned `ResultSet` is **never** `null`. You really need to invoke `ResultSet#next()` to set the cursor to the next row. Its default position is namely *before* the first row. Not doing that would only result in

So, just replace

```
if(rs != null){
```

by

```
if (rs.next()) {
```

and you should be all set.

If you intend to handle the "no results found" case, just do it in the `else` of the `if`:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    // At least one record found.
} else {
    // No records found.
}
```

#### See also:

- [retrieving data from mysql select statement in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795507/retreiving-data-from-mysql-select-statement-in-java/5795554#5795554)
- [JDBC driver throws "ResultSet Closed" exception on empty ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813858/sqlite-3-jdbc-driver-throws-resultsset-closed-exception-on-empty-resultset/1814443#1814443)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this code has other severe problems: there's a huge SQL injection attack hole and the DB resources are being leaked away. This is not right.

#### See also:

- [how to prevent SQL Injection in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272861/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-jsp/6272885#6272885)
- [JDBC MySql connection pooling practices to avoid exhausted connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313197/jdbc-mysql-connection-pooling-practices/2313262#2313262)

Comment: I tried that. It comes out of the if because there's only single record in rs.

Comment: No, that would only happen if there is no record matching the query :)

Comment: Yes there's no record in rs. How do I check if time==null?

Comment: Just do the job in `else` block of the `if`. Please see also the "see also" links for more hints/tips for the right approaches.

Comment: Got the error it was returning empty set. The query should  be 

> rs = stmt.executeQuery("select block_no from vehicle where vehicle_no='"+veh_no+"' and out_time is NULL");

Just replaced '=' with 'is' .